# spring web mvc application not running on Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.2

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

when i run my spring web mvc application with tomcat 8 its running fine. but when i run same application with Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.2 it show message in console **Servlet Context Stoppped** and show error on page as below:
[image]

Comment: I guess you just dragged&dropped the app in STS to the installed tc Server instance, right? Is there any error showing up in the console view when you start the server with your app deployed?

Answer (score 0):

I was using JNDI and connection was established using **mysql-connector-java** copied in **lib** folder of tomcat. I did not copy same file in new configuration. Now i added **mysql-connector-java** in **pom.xml** and it resolved the issue.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
```